# how to urldecode a request_uri string in Lua

Tags: nginx, lua

When I use `ngx.var.request_uri` I'm getting back a string that contains %20 in place of spaces.  Is there a urldecode() function or similar to decode my string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The decoded URI can be found in `ngx.var.uri`. It does not contain the query string, if you need it see `ngx.var.query_string`.

EDIT: if you cannot use this, here is a simple way to unescape a URL in Lua.

```
local hex_to_char = function(x)
  return string.char(tonumber(x, 16))
end

local unescape = function(url)
  return url:gsub("%%(%x%x)", hex_to_char)
end
```

Example usage:

```
local url = "/test/some%20string?foo=bar"
print(unescape(url)) -- /test/some string?foo=bar
```

But you should probably split the query string *before* using it.

Comment: When I visit /abc and my config bounces me through a 404 using `error_page 404 /test`, when I access `ngx.var.uri` it's equal to /test rather than /abc.  However, `ngx.var.request_uri` evaluates to /abc

Comment: OK, I have edited my answer to give you another option that actually unescapes the URL in Lua.

Comment: I wish there was a way to do this inline.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using [nginx-lua-module](https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module)  then you can use below api for this.

```
newstr = ngx.unescape_uri(str)
```

You can also take a look of
[ngxescape_uri](https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module#ngxescape_uri)

Answer (score 2):

Try `ngx.req` api from `nginx-lua-module`

- `ngx.req.set_uri` : rewrite uri, rewrite path only, use`ngx.req.set_uri_args` if u also want replace params
- `ngx.escape_uri`: for encode string
- `ngx.unescape_uri`: for decode string

For Example: decode path & args

```
location / {
  .....

  rewrite_by_lua_block {
       # Get nginx var $uri , ucant change to $request_uri ,$args ...
       local uri = ngx.var.uri

       # use api below to decode args
       ngx.req.set_uri_args(ngx.unescape_uri(ngx.var.args));

       # use set_uri to decode path
       ngx.req.set_uri(ngx.unescape_uri(uri));
  }
}
  proxy_pass ....;
```

Ref. Document : https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqset_uri

Answer (score 0):

[LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/) has a [`url.unescape`](http://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/url.html#unescape) utility. Quoting:

> `url.unescape(content)`
>
> Removes the URL escaping content coding from a string.
>
> Content is the string to be decoded.
>
> The function returns the decoded string.