# Lua - decodeURI (luvit)

Tags: lua, urldecode, encodeuricomponent, decodeuricomponent

I would like to use `decodeURI` or `decodeURIComponent` as in JavaScript in my **Lua (Luvit)** project.

JavaScript:

```
decodeURI('%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82')
// result: привет
```

Luvit:

```
require('querystring').urldecode('%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82')
-- result: '%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82'
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20282998/107090 for some code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is trivial to do yourself in Lua if you understand the [URI percent-encoded format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1). Each `%XX` substring represents UTF-8 data encoded with a `%` prefix and a hexadecimal octet.

```lua
local decodeURI
do
    local char, gsub, tonumber = string.char, string.gsub, tonumber
    local function _(hex) return char(tonumber(hex, 16)) end

    function decodeURI(s)
        s = gsub(s, '%%(%x%x)', _)
        return s
    end
end

print(decodeURI('%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82'))
```

Comment: You can use `%%(%x%x)` as the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another take. This code will save you lots of function calls if you have to decode many strings.

```
local hex = {}
for i = 0, 255 do
    hex[string.format("%02x", i)] = string.char(i)
    hex[string.format("%02X", i)] = string.char(i)
end

local function decodeURI(s)
    return (s:gsub('%%(%x%x)', hex))
end

print(decodeURI('%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82'))
```

Comment: Interesting. You're caching all the possible percent-encoded hex octets, upper and lowercase, into a lookup table for use by `gsub`. The only thing I notice about this is the corner case where you might get a mixed-case octet such as `Fe`, but I doubt that would happen in practice.

Comment: code doesn't work for the first 16 characters `hex[string.format("%02x",i)]=string.char(i)` add a 2 before the x

Answer (score 0):

URIs represent `' '` with `'+'`
And other special characters are represented as a percent followed by the 2 digit hex character code `'%0A'` for `'\n'` for example

```
local function decodeCharacter(code)
    -- get the number for the hex code 
    --   then get the character for that number
    return string.char(tonumber(code, 16))
end

function decodeURI(s)
    -- first replace '+' with ' '
    --   then, on the resulting string, decode % encoding
    local str = s:gsub("+", " ")
        :gsub('%%(%x%x)', decodeCharacter)
    return str 
    -- assignment to str removes the second return value of gsub
end

print(decodeURI('he%79+there%21')) -- prints "hey there!"
```