# Lua routine to decode query argument

Tags: lua, url-encoding

Is there an open source lua routine to decode query arguments conforming to RFC 3986? Specifically query arguments can be split by a ; or & i.e. field=value&field1=value1. How does one get to know if a particular query argument is separated by a i.e field=value;field1=value1. I can probably scan for the the token but apparently the field and value may also contain a ;. 
Since this is an often used functionality, I was wondering if there is a Lua library that will take care of all the corner cases.

Comment: May be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24885743/1847592

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `url` namespace in Luasocket module to parse URLs. The documentation is [available here](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/url.html).

A sample code (and output) would be like:

```
> l = require 'socket.url'
> x = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&pli=1#inbox'
> z = l.parse(x)
> for k, v in pairs(z) do print(k,v) end
host    mail.google.com
fragment    inbox
query   ui=2&pli=1
scheme  https
path    /mail/u/0/
authority   mail.google.com
```