# Rewriting %3F, etc. to special characters ( ? and = ) Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

Hi I got a problem with my server. I got 4 inbound links to webpage which look something like this:

myurl.com/default/page.php%3Fid%3D13

they should look like this:

myurl.com/default/page.php?id=13

What would I need to do to achive this? Apache spits out 404 errors when you visit an encoded url link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution (although I wouldn't say it's a good one) is to set up a 404 handler which tries to decode the URL. Maybe you can do some fancy matching to try to guess whether the 404 is due to the URL being encoded.

```
if(stripos($url, '%3F') !== false){
    header('Location: ' . urldecode($url) );
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)? It looks like you are getting the URL encoded somehow. If urldecode doesn't do the trick, then you could write a function to decode those particular characters using a map like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: How would this be done? Newbie here.

In the nginx server config?

Comment: it's not the php that's the problem - it's that sites link to a url with "page.php%3Fid%3D13 " which causes 404. it should be "page.php?id=13"

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry, I assumed you were getting it in PHP since your question was tagged with PHP. I'm not familiar with nginx, I'll look around.

Comment: It looks like nginx has its own functions as described [here](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,230121,230123)

Comment: Also check this [S/O](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282054/how-to-urldecode-a-request-uri-string-in-lua) article out.

Answer (score 0):

nginx separates the requested filename from the args, and operates on normalised URIs, therefore, in the `location` and in the first argument to `rewrite`, the `%3F` part can only be matched directly by the `?` character (whereas explicit `?` from the request will never make it up here), as such:

```
rewrite     ^/([^?]*)\?(.*)$    /$1?$2?     permanent;
```

Some more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21144014/1122270